# connect ENOENT error when connecting to Google Cloud SQL from App Engine / localhost

Tags: google-cloud-platform, strapi

I have a next.js-strapi v4 app hosted on google cloud app engine.
The database is postgreSql and hosted on google cloud sql.
The files are also hosted on gcp.
Since the deployment to Google App Engine is missing from the strapi v4 documentation, I used that  [guide on medium](https://blog.rahulbharati.dev/how-to-deploy-strapi-with-postgresql-on-google-app-engine-3d5071272124).

when I run the app using:

```
gcloud app deploy app.yaml
```

I get this error:

```
debug: ⛔️ Server wasn't able to start properly.
error: connect ENOENT /cloudsql/INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME/.s.PGSQL.5432
 at PipeConnectWrap.afterConnect
```

this is the app.yaml:

```
runtime: nodejs16

instance_class: F2

env_variables:
  NODE_ENV: 'production'

beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: <INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>
```

this is database.js:

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  connection: {
    client: "postgres",
    connection: {
      host: `/cloudsql/${env('INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME')}`,
      port: env.int("DATABASE_PORT", 5432),
      database: env("DATABASE_NAME", "strapi"),
      user: env("DATABASE_USERNAME", ""),
      password: env("DATABASE_PASSWORD", ""),
    },
  },
});
```

This is what I have already did:

1. enable the Cloud SQL Admin API
2. add Cloud SQL Client role to my App Engine default service account
3. expose the virtual machine ip and my local ip to the Authorized networks of the database
4. run "gcloud auth application-default login" on the google cloud sdk
5. made a successful connectivity test with my ip using the CONNECTIVITY TESTS tab

I also tried to connect to the gcp database from my local app but got the same error.

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solution 1

you have to grants access through cloud sql auth proxy
[documentation for config cloud sql with app engine standard environment](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-instance-app-engine)

solution 2

1. first you have to create virtual private cloud (VPC) from gcp.
2. then add you cloud sql instance ip to VPC network peering
3. then create Serverless VPC access connector with 28 CIDR range
   subnet in your VPC
4. finally mention your adapter name in app.yaml

[configure vpc peering](https://cloud.google.com/database-migration/docs/postgres/configure-connectivity-vpc-peering)

[configure serverless vpc access connector](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/serverless-vpc-access)

if you are host using app engine flexible environment no need to creatre serverless VPC access connector